# Add combobox to selected file Visual Studio 2010 VB

Tags: visual-studio-2010, excel, vba, combobox

i want to make an .exe file using VS2010 to select excel file, and read it's sheets through a combobox.

I have now sorted to make a 'browse' button to select the excel file and generate a msgbox but yet couldn't assign the combobox to read it's sheets.

here is my code

Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Form1

```
Public Sub btnBrowse_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBrowse.Click
    Dim myFileDlog As New OpenFileDialog()
    'Dim oXL As Excel.Application
    'Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook
    'Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet


    'look for files in the c drive
    myFileDlog.InitialDirectory = "c:\"

    'specifies what type of data files to look for
    myFileDlog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*" & _
        "|Data Files (*.xls)|*.xls" & _
        "|Data Files (*.xlsx*)|*.xlsx*" & _
        "|Data Files (*.xlsm*)|*.xlsm*"

    'specifies which data type is focused on start up
    myFileDlog.FilterIndex = 2

    'Gets or sets a value indicating whether the dialog box restores the current directory before closing.
    myFileDlog.RestoreDirectory = True

    'seperates message outputs for files found or not found
    If myFileDlog.ShowDialog() = _
        DialogResult.OK Then
        If Dir(myFileDlog.FileName) <> "" Then
            MsgBox("File Exists: " & _
                   myFileDlog.FileName, _
                   MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        Else
            MsgBox("File Not Found", _
                   MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End If
    End If

    'Adds the file directory to the text box
    txtFileDirectory.Text = myFileDlog.FileName
End Sub

Public Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    'Dim oXL As Excel.Application
    Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    'Dim oRng As Excel.Range

    For x As Integer = 1 To FileDialog.Sheets.Count()
        If TypeOf oWB.Sheets(x) Is Excel.Worksheet Then
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(FileDialog.Sheets(x).name)
        End If
    Next
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
End Sub
```

End Class

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your workbook `oWB` first and then use the below.

Change

```
    If TypeOf oWB.Sheets(x) Is Excel.Worksheet Then
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(FileDialog.Sheets(x).name)
    End If
```

to

```
    If TypeOf oWB.Sheets(x) Is Excel.Worksheet Then
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(oWB.Sheets(x).name)
    End If
```

Similarly `FileDialog.Sheets.Count()` is incorrect